# recursive method not properly executing

Tags: java, recursion, subset-sum

I have a programming assignment for an introductory level Java class (the subset sum problem) - for some reason, my recursive method isn't executing properly (it just goes straight to the end of the method and prints out the sorted list).  Any help would be appreciated - I'm a newbie and recursive functions are really confusing to me.

```
package programmingassignment3;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class ProgrammingAssignment3 {

    static int TARGET = 10;
    static ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    static int SIZE = list.size();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        populateSortSet();
        sumInt(list);
        recursiveSS(list);
    }//main

    public static void populateSortSet() {
        try {
            File f = new File("set0.txt");
            Scanner input = new Scanner(f);
            while (input.hasNext()) {
                int ele = input.nextInt();
                if (ele < TARGET && !list.contains(ele)) {
                    list.add(ele);
                }//if
            }//while
            Collections.sort(list);
        }//try
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }//catch
    }//populateSet

    public static void recursiveSS(ArrayList<Integer> Alist) {
        if (Alist.size() == SIZE) {
            if (sumInt(Alist) == TARGET) {
                System.out.println("The integers that equal " + TARGET + "are: " + Alist);
            } //if==TARGET  
        }//if==SIZE
        else {
            for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
                ArrayList<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<>(Alist);
                ArrayList<Integer> list0 = new ArrayList<>(Alist);
                list1.add(1);
                list0.add(0);
                if (sumInt(list0) < TARGET) {
                    recursiveSS(list0);
                }//if
                if (sumInt(list1) < TARGET) {
                    recursiveSS(list1);
                }//if
            }//for
        }//else
        System.out.println("echo" + Alist);
    }//recursiveSS

    public static int sumInt(ArrayList<Integer> Alist) {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < SIZE - 1; i++) {
            sum += Alist.get(i);
        }//for
        if (Alist.size() == TARGET) {
            sum += Alist.get(Alist.size() - 1);
        }//if
        return sum;
    }//sumInt
}//class
```

Comment: Please remove all those awful comments (e.g. "//if" and "//class") from your code.  They only clutter and don't add value.  Recursion starts with identifying the stopping condition.  What is it for what you're trying to do?  Can you spell out the subset sum problem in English?

Comment: @duffymo there's no right or wrong opinion regarding closing brace comments. the author says she's in an introductory programming class. if this helps her remember how the braces match up, then it's a good practice. i occasionally use it in C when my nested `#ifdef`s get confusing.

Comment: @WoodrowBarlow - I think there is.  No profession indulges in such clutter.  This is what real IDEs are for.  Even Eclipse can manage it for you.  It's worth hearing.

Comment: The closing brace comments are actually required by my professor.  I'm still working through this - thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I'd do it.  I hope it clarifies the stopping condition and the recursion.   As you can see, static methods are not an issue:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Demo of recursion
 * User: mduffy
 * Date: 10/3/2014
 * Time: 10:56 AM
 * @link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26179574/recursive-method-not-properly-executing?noredirect=1#comment41047653_26179574
 */
public class RecursionDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> values = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (String arg : args) {
            values.add(Integer.valueOf(arg));
        }
        System.out.println(String.format("input values : %s", values));
        System.out.println(String.format("iterative sum: %d", getSumUsingIteration(values)));
        System.out.println(String.format("recursive sum: %d", getSumUsingRecursion(values)));
    }

    public static int getSumUsingIteration(List<Integer> values) {
        int sum = 0;
        if (values != null) {
            for (int value : values) {
                sum += value;
            }
        }
        return sum;
    }

    public static int getSumUsingRecursion(List<Integer> values) {
        if ((values == null) || (values.size() == 0)) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            if (values.size() == 1) { // This is the stopping condition
                return values.get(0);
            } else {
                return values.get(0) + getSumUsingRecursion(values.subList(1, values.size())); // Here is recursion
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the case I used to test it:

```
input values : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
iterative sum: 21
recursive sum: 21

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 1):

This thing that you do at class level:

```
static ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
static int SIZE = list.size();
```

means that SIZE will be initiated to `0`, and stay `0` (even if you add elements to the list.)

This means that the code inside the `for-loop` will be executed 0 times.

Try something like:

```
public class ProgrammingAssignment3 {
    private static int initialSize;

    //...
    public static void populateSortSet() {
        //populate the list
        initialSize = list.size();
    }
```

So you don't set the value of the size variable until the list is actually populated.

That being said, there a quite a few other strange things in your code, so I think you need to specify exactly what you are trying to solve here.

Comment: is this because of the static keyword?

Comment: No, it is the same with non-static variables. You assign the `int` by value, not by reference, so it will have the value of the size of the list at the time of assignment.

Comment: oh, i didn't even notice that OP had created a variable for size. I glanced at the code and assumed you meant `list.size()` would always be zero and was confused.

Comment: The point of the subset sum problem, as explained by my professor, is to enter a data set (arraylist - imported from a .txt file) and then find a subset of that list that adds up to a target integer, being sure to delete any duplicate elements and any elements greater than the target integer. For an example, S={2, 6, 8, 5, 1, 10} and Target = 9, there are two subsets (solutions): S1={2, 6, 1} and S2={8, 1}.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone.  I really appreciate the help.  I did figure out the problem and the solution is as follows (closing brace comments removed for the reading pleasure of @duffymo ):

```
public class ProgrammingAssignment3 {

    static int TARGET = 6233;
    static ArrayList<Integer> set = new ArrayList<>();
    static int SIZE;
    static int count = 0;

    public static void populateSortSet() {
        try {
            File f = new File("set3.txt");
            Scanner input = new Scanner(f);
            while (input.hasNext()) {
                int ele = input.nextInt();
                if (ele < TARGET && !set.contains(ele)) {
                    set.add(ele);
                }
            }
            Collections.sort(set);
            SIZE = set.size();
            System.out.println("The original sorted set: " + set + "\t subset sum = " + TARGET);
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void recursiveSS(ArrayList<Integer> list) {
        if (list.size() == SIZE) {
            if (sumInt(list) == TARGET) {
                System.out.print("The Bit subset is: " + list + "\t");
                System.out.println("The subset is: " + getSubset(list));
                count++;
            }  
        }
        else {
            ArrayList<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<>(list);//instantiate list1
            ArrayList<Integer> list0 = new ArrayList<>(list);//instantiate list0
            list1.add(1);
            list0.add(0);
            if (sumInt(list0) <= TARGET) {
                recursiveSS(list0);
            }
            if (sumInt(list1) <= TARGET) {
                recursiveSS(list1);
            }
        }
    }

    public static int sumInt(ArrayList<Integer> list) {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            if (list.get(i) == 1) {
                sum += set.get(i);
            }
        }
        return sum;
    }

    public static ArrayList<Integer> getSubset(ArrayList<Integer> list) {
        ArrayList<Integer> l = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            if (list.get(i) == 1) {
                l.add(set.get(i));
            }
        }
        return l;
    }
}
```